# Whatsapp API send links, change display name and image

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have integrated the whatsapp API to my backend; the templates are approved, I have sent some test messages to myself and I see that

- My Display Name is not visible for the receiver; neither am I able to see the image which I have setup
- I am using this for transactional operations and I have url's in the message which is not clickable until either the user responds to the message or accepts message from the sender.

Is there a way for me to fix this either from the settings or from the api perspective.